# Return two Chars from a method receiving a String

Tags: c#, string, methods, char

I'm trying to return two Chars from a method that takes a string. Say the method receives the word "Hello", and i want to return the first and last letter = ho. I've made a method that takes a string and returns one char. But i don't know how to return two.

Comment: Its hard to see whats wrong with a piece of code without that code present.

Answer (score 2):

You can return char[] - array of characters.

The method signature will become something like this:

```
public static char[] GetFirstAndLastChars(string input)
{
   var result = new char[2];

   //your code to take first and last letters   
   result[0] = inputString.FirstOrDefault();
   result[1] = inputString.LastOrDefault();

   return result;
}
```

As mentioned in other answers, you can turn this into extension method if used frequently.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done quite easily using a extension method returning a `char[]`.
Complete example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myString = "abc";
        var firstAndLast = myString.GetFirstAndLast();
        Console.WriteLine("First: " + firstAndLast[0] + " Last: " + firstAndLast[1]);
    }

}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static char[] GetFirstAndLast(this string str)
    {
        return new char[2] { str.FirstOrDefault(), str.LastOrDefault() };
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
First: a Last: c
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `char[]` from your input and return the first and last element of that `char[]`:

```
public char[] GetChars(string input)
{
    char[] charArray = input.ToCharArray();
    char[] result = new char[] { charArray.First(), charArray.Last() };

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try this:

```
public struct Ends
{
    public char Front;
    public char Back;
}

public Ends GetEnds(string text)
{
    return new Ends() { Front = text.First(), Back = text.Last() };
}
```

You would obviously call it like:

```
Ends ends = GetEnds("hello");
```

I get this result:

[image: Ends]

Answer (score -1):

Return any type of data structure holding both of the chars. I would probably return the string "ho", but you can also return an array or a tuple.